# Fixing Youtube Video Loading C# Webbrowser?

Tags: c#, video, browser, youtube, load

So I'm making my application load a webpage using an IP address from a list and loading up a Youtube video. The problem is it loads up as basic html and looks terrible. I tried it with other websites like Google and Yahoo and the images and everything load correctly. Here is what I'm using to load the page:

```
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
        webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(finalList[proxies]);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
```

Any idea on how to make the page load correctly?

Comment: You might need to add a `<base href="http://www.youtube.com/">` to the `<head>`

Comment: You can't use youtube like this, as yiz need the player to run in your web browser. Try loading a page to your browser that contains the line to embed the player as it is described on the page with the video (something with `<div.../>`)